# Uses API Beatport with node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to use the API Beatport with Node.js, but I've a error, I not how to recover the token to make requests to API. In my code I not know to reference the correct URI.

I search very much for the Internet, I not find the a reference the use de API, the petition in token.

Please could you help me.

Sorry for my bad orthography and gramatica, the English is not my first language.

--
This is my code

```
`var OAuth = require('OAuth');
var oauth = new OAuth.OAuth(
  'https://oauth-api.beatport.com/identity/1/oauth/request-token',
  'https://oauth-api.beatport.com/identity/1/oauth/access-token',
  'my_API KEY',
  'my_API SECRET',
  '1.0A',
  null,
  'HMAC-SHA1'
);
oauth.get(
  'https://oauth-api.beatport.com/catalog/3/artists/8637',
    'my_API KEY', 
    'my_API SECRET', 
  function (e, data, res){
    if (e) 
        console.error(e);        
    //console.log(require(res);

  });   `
```

Comment: How knowledgeable are you of the OAuth1 Auth flow? I can't tell from what you're asking which step in the process is broken. See if this doc helps you clarify where you are in the process, revise your question a bit, and then maybe I can produce an answer: https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Auth-Flow.html